# Perl issue extracting, manipulating and merging related data from different lines

Tags: perl, parsing, merge

**I have a very specific problem that I am having trouble solving, it is relating to parsing and merging related data from different lines**

I have a file that contains text in the format shown below:

```
======================================================
8:27:24 PM  http://10.11.12.13:80
======================================================
GET /dog-pictures HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.11.12.13
Language: english
Agent: Unknown
Connection: closed

======================================================



======================================================
8:28:56 PM  http://192.114.126.245:80
======================================================
GET /flowers HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.11.12.13
Language: english

======================================================



======================================================
8:29:07 PM  http://10.11.12.13:80
======================================================
GET /africas-animals HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.11.12.13
Language: english
Agent: Unknown
Connection: open

======================================================
```

As you can see above each *group* of data  in the text file is made up of three rows of equals signs (=======), but can contain a different number of rows of data within that.

**The format I need the output to be in is as follows:**

```
    http://10.11.12.13/dog-pictures
    http://192.114.126.245/flowers
    http://10.11.12.13/africas-animals
```

**Explanation of the bits I need merged:**

```
======================================================
8:27:24 PM  http://10.11.12.13:80                     <--- Gets the first part from here**
======================================================
GET /dog-pictures HTTP/1.1                            <--- Gets the seconds part from here**
Host: 10.11.12.13
Language: english
Agent: Unknown
Connection: closed

======================================================
```

**Your help with this problem is much appreciated, 
                                                 thank you in advance**

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Ive tried a number of different things, mainly consisting of getting rid of the strings I don't need e.g $sLine =~ s/GET //g; and $sLine =~ s/HTTP\/1\.1//g; and so on, but I don't know how to associate the ip address on the first line with the '/dog-pictures' part on the second line and put them together (for each section of the text file). Also the ways I have tried are done in a very roundabout way.

Comment: @TLP I have parsed files and manipulated strings and so on before but this example is more complicated than ones I have done before, thanks for your help.

Comment: The best way to parse this would be to use a module. I'm looking for something to parse this sort of log, but it would be helpful to know where it came from.

Comment: @TLP - It is a burp spider log that I have used to spider my site with, I took some of the detail out of the log for the purpose of explaining my problem but it is essentially what the output looks like, thanks

Comment: One way I was thinking it could be done was by setting a flag when it comes across the first line of equals signs, then capturing the lines with the data I need then stop capturing when it comes to the last line of equals, but im not sure how to go about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following will assist you:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'data.txt' or die $!;

# Read a file line
while (<$fh>) {

    # If url captured on line beginning with time and read (separator) line
    if ( my ($url) = /^\d+:\d+:\d+.+?(\S+):\d+$/ and <$fh> ) {

        # Capture path
        my ($path) = <$fh> =~ /\s+(\/\S+)\s+/;

        print "$url$path\n" if $url and $path;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
http://10.11.12.13/dog-pictures
http://192.114.126.245/flowers
http://10.11.12.13/africas-animals
```

There are only two lines that contain the information you want, and those are separated by a line of equal signs.  The first regex tries to match a time string and capture the url on that line.  The `and <$fh>` is used to get past the separator.  The second regex captures the path on the next line.  Finally, the url and path are printed.

Comment: thankyou for your answer, it does exactly what i require. The only issue is to do with capturing the path. I have found that sometimes instead of the path being '/dog-pictures' or '/flowers' it is simply '/'. What would I have to change to the 'my ($path) = <$fh> =~ /\s+(\/\S+)\s+/;' regular expression to accommodate this '/' path? Thanks for your help.

Comment: apologies for a stupid question, just realised why i couldn't get the regular expression to work, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this in `Perl` in a `shell`:

```
perl -lane '
    if (/^\d+:\d+:\d+\s+\w+\s+([^:]+):/) {
        $scheme = $1;
    }
    if (/^(GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|DELETE|OPTION|TRACE)/) {
        $path = $F[1];
    }
    if (/^Host/) {
        print "$scheme://$F[1]$path";
    }
' file.txt
```

### SCRIPT VERSION

generated by `perl -MO=Deparse` with a bit of tweaking...

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# mimic `-l` switch to print like "say"
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }

use strict; use warnings;

my ($scheme, $path);

# magic diamond operator
while (<ARGV>) {
    chomp $_;
    # splitting current line in @F array
    my (@F) = split(' ', $_, 0);

    # regex to catch the scheme (http)
    if (/^\d+:\d+:\d+\s+\w+\s+([^:]+):/) {
        $scheme = $1;
    }
    # if the current line match an HTTP verb, we feed $path variable
    # with second column
    if (/^(GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|DELETE|OPTION|TRACE)/) {
        $path = $F[1];
    }
    # if the current line match HOST, we print the needed line
    if (/^Host/) {
        print "${scheme}://$F[1]$path";
    }
}
```

### USAGE

```
chmod +x script.pl
./script.pl file.txt
```

### OUTPUT

```
http://10.11.12.13/dog-pictures
http://10.11.12.13/flowers
http://10.11.12.13/africas-animals
```

Comment: Would you be a show a script way of doing this as opposed to a one-liner if possible please as this will form part of a much larger script, thank you very much for your help and I understand the way your one-liner works.

Comment: I have never used what you have written in your note before so will have to look into it. Would you be able to add some comments to your code above so I can better understand it (i obviously understand the ip address regex and GET | HEAD | POST parts) thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Perl:

```
perl -F -lane 'if(/http/){$x=$F[2]}if(/GET/){print $x.$F[1]}' your_file
```

if you would want to go for awk:

```
awk '/http/{x=$3}/GET/{print x""substr($2,1)}' your_file
```

Comment: Couldn't get the Perl one-liner to work.  Its output is `2E\n2E\n2E\n`.  Also, in comments to an answer, the OP states a desire for a commented script.